Clicking 'Edit' on a revision on a Staging Ground post edits latest revision, not the selected revision
Normally, you are able to click the "Edit" link on a revision in the revision history of a post, next to "Rollback" and "Link".
This allows you to edit that specific revision, essentially rolling back the subsequent edits, and then submitting your edit. You will even be shown a message:

Warning!
You're editing an old revision. If you save it, you will effectively roll back to this old version of the post.

However, when I try this on a Staging Ground post, I am still shown the source for the latest revision, rather than the source for the revision I selected.
